When cell changed, to offset copy and paste action into different cells of same row
I used this code to offset timestamp after change of cell.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b2:b888")) Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next

If Target.Value = "" Then

Target.Offset(0, 1) = ""

Else

Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Format(Now, "HH:mm")


End If
End If


End Sub

Now I would like to change from timestamp to specific value from that row.
So on edit of "b2" it would paste into "c2" value from "w2".
Not sure how to get this done smooth with offset for each row to work that no separate codes for each cell are needed.
Thank you
I tried combining copy paste codes instead of timestamps offset but nothing seems to stick nicely together.

That's a Vba question, not a VB6 one!

Got it,
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim AffectedRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range
' Check if the changed cell is in column B
Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B"))
If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' To prevent triggering the event again
    
    ' Loop through each changed cell in column B
    For Each Cell In AffectedRange
        ' Copy value from column W to corresponding cell in column C
        Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value = Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "W").Value
    Next Cell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable events
End If

End Sub
